# Collapse a list of lists, grouping on specific element and appending other elements

Tags: python, list, grouping, python-itertools

How could I transform a list such as:

```
l=[ ['A', 'C21'], ['A','D43'],['B','D34'],['C','D45'],['C',D56']
```

to:

```
[ ['A','C21 D43'], ['B','D34'],['C','D45 D56'] ]
```

Where the grouping is performed according to element #0 of each sub list
and elements #1 are string concatenated within each group?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
l=[ ['A', 'C21'], ['A','D43'],['B','D34'],['C','D45'],['C','D56']]
x = {}

for a in l:
    if a[0] not in x.keys():
        x[a[0]] = [a[1]]
    else:
        x[a[0]].append(a[1])

print x

array_result = []
for keys, vals in x.iteritems():
    array_result.append([keys, ' '.join(vals)])

print array_result
```

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are contiguous then you can use `itertools.groupby`, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby

data =[ ['A', 'C21'], ['A','D43'],['B','D34'],['C','D45'],['C','D56'] ]
new_data = [[k, ' '.join(el[1] for el in g)] for k, g in groupby(data, lambda L: L[0])]
# [['A', 'C21 D43'], ['B', 'D34'], ['C', 'D45 D56']]
```

If not and order doesn't really matter, then:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in data:
    dd[key].append(val)

new_data = [[k, ' '.join(v)] for k,v in dd.items()]
# [['B', 'D34'], ['C', 'D45 D56'], ['A', 'C21 D43']]
```

Alternatively - make use of `dict.setdefault`, eg:

```
d = {}
for key, val in data:
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
new_data = [[k, ' '.join(v)] for k,v in d.items()]
```

Or, if the keys aren't contiguous, but the output should maintain the order of the input, then use `collections.OrderedDict`, eg:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for key, val in data:
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(val)

new_data = [[k, ' '.join(v)] for k,v in d.items()]
# [['A', 'C21 D43'], ['B', 'D34'], ['C', 'D45 D56']]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, PNV and Bhargav for your great answers! I do need ordered output so will probably use the groupby or orderdict.

Comment: @user3843673 In Stack Overflow we say thank you by marking answers. Kindly mark Jon's answer as accepted. See this image for reference - http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png And this meta post for your understanding http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work All the best in your future work too!